# Green video on google hangout/chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dell, gpu-driver, google-hangouts

I am running a Dell Inspiron 5556 with Ubuntu 15.10. Just got linux on it and things are mostly good.

I am able to run hangouts fine in Firefox. However, in Chrome, the video is completely green. I have been unable to find references to this phenomenon.

[image: green video screenshot]

Comment: Could https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/EM3N9h9gcII be related to this?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am running 16.04 and got the same problem on hangouts.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you have a laptop equipped with an [Intel RealSense camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_RealSense). The camera is meant for motion detection and the lines you see are distance contours.

I had the same problem. It turned out that `/dev/video0` was pointing to this camera instead of the webcam (which was at `/dev/video1`). The camera used for other webcam-based applications in Google Chrome can be set through `Settings -> Content settings -> Camera`, but Google Hangouts does not respect this choice and insists on using whatever is at `/dev/video0` (perhaps because the choice is made through the Google talk plugin rather than Chrome).

I solved this problem by writing a bash function to switch `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1` so that Hangouts picks the right camera. Clearly a hack and there should be a better way to do this, but it works!

Comment: i have the same problem, but cant acces my main camera in content settings could you share your bash function?

Comment: I did just the dumbest possible thing possible: `sudo mv /dev/video0 /dev/videotemp; sudo mv /dev/video1 /dev/video0; sudo mv /dev/videotemp /dev/video1`

Answer (score 0):

At least as of now, you can select the camera device in Google Hangouts: click on vertical ... -> Settings -> General tab -> Video and select the desired camera from the drop down.